# Webview2 SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping not allowed to load local resource

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

Hey all I am using the new WebView2 with my WinForms app. I can get it to display my dynamic html that I create but it has the "" when it tries to load the images for the page.

[image]

The image tag looks like this:

```
<div id="animation1" style="display: inline-flex;">
   <img src="file:///C:\Users\admin\source\repos\wCondictions\bin\x86\Debug\Resources/nice.gif" style="height: 110px; width: 110px;">
   <span class="imgWeather">Nice</span>
</div>
```

The code I am currently using is this:

```
fileNames = new DirectoryInfo(resourcePath)
            .GetFiles()
            .OrderBy(p => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(p.Name))
            .Select(fi => fi.Name)
            .ToArray();
string blah = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Resources");
string fullHtml = string.Empty;
string HeaderHtml = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
                        "<html>\n" +
                        "<style>\n" +
                            ".imgW {\n" +
                                "position: absolute;\n" +
                                "z-index: 10;\n" +
                                "color: red;\n" +
                                "width: 110px;\n" +
                                "height:30px;\n" +
                                "text-align: center;\n" +
                                "vertical-align: middle;\n" +
                                "top: 88px;\n" +
                                "background-color: aquamarine;\n" +
                                "font-family: Arial;\n" +
                                "font-size: small;\n" +
                            "}\n" +
                        "</style>\n" +
                        "<body style=\"background-color: #00000;\">";
string dynamixImg = "<div id=\"animation1\" style=\"display: inline-flex;\">\n" +
                                "<img src=\"file:///" + blah + "/{0}\" style=\"height: 110px; width: 110px;\" />\n" +
                                "<span class=\"imgW\">{1}</span>\n" +
                            "</div>";
string FooterHtml = "</body>" +
                        "</html>";

for (int a = 0; a < fileNames.Count(); a++)
{
    fullHtml += string.Format(
                dynamixImg, 
                fileNames[a], 
                fileNames[a]
                .Replace(".gif", "")
                .Replace("&", "&&") 
    ) + "\n";
}

await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();

webView21.CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping(
            "Resources", 
            @"C:\Users\admin\source\repos\wCondictions\bin\x86\Debug\Resources\", 
            CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.Allow
);

webView21.NavigateToString(HeaderHtml + fullHtml + FooterHtml);
```

I've seen many places where it says to use the **SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping** but even with that it still says the same error.

So I am not sure what I am missing or misunderstanding about how to use the **SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping** in order to allow the images to load locally?

Comment: After you have used `SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping` you should change the links to relative links. Have you done that?

Comment: @PoulBak that link just shows regular HTML without images. If i didn't have the images then my HTML would work also.

Comment: @PoulBak and could you explain your first comment a little better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To follow up on this, and to give a clear example, this is what you need to do. This works with the current WebView2 control as of 2023 (which is version 1.0.1671-prerelease). You may need to adjust syntax on different versions.

This code sets up the folder mapping:

```
string resourcePath = @"C:\Users\{username}\{sourcepath}\Resources\";
WebView2.CoreWebView2.SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping("MyFiles", resourcePath, CoreWebView2HostResourceAccessKind.Allow);
```

Then instead of referencing a local path like

```
<img src="file:///C:\images\image.png">
```

in your HTML string, you now reference

```
<img src="http://MyFiles/image.png">
```

then finally call

```
WebView2.CoreWebView2.NavigateToString(myhtml);
```

and your local image will display correctly in the page.

This also will work for an end-user if you publish the app as a ClickOnce application.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I will try again, my first answer was confusing.

You get the error because you use the `file://` protocol.

It seems you have not fully understood the the use of `SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping`.

**Once you have set the virtual server by calling `SetVirtualHostNameToFolderMapping` you should use that virtual server just as you use any other server on the internet. Do NOT use `file://`!**

So all you have to do is edit your `HeaderHtml` and your `<img src`.

The `HeaderHtml` should include a `<base>` tag, which should point to your virtual server root:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="http://Resources" />
    </head>
```

That makes it very easy to build you dynamic `<ìmg>` tags, **the source is simply the file name:**

```
<img src="image.png" />
```

Now `WebView2`will translate it into a file path and fetch the image!

As a side note, you can also include files from sub-folder by adding the folder name in front of the file name, like this:

```
<img src="/subfolder/image.png" />
```